# Json.Net: Getting keys out of JToken

Tags: c#, json.net

Is there any way to get the keys out of a `JToken` object? (that means not JObject and just JToken)

Unlike `JObject` this type return a collection and so far I have not been able to get the keys but just values in string format.

For example:

```
var raw = JRaw.Parse(x);
foreach(var i in raw){
    // Get the key of i
    // Get the value of i
}
```

I need to emphasize that I only and only want to use this approach and do not want to go for a different solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over all `JProperty` elements:

```
foreach(JProperty prop in raw.OfType<JProperty>())
{
   Console.WriteLine($"{prop.Name} = {prop.Value}");
}
```

If you know that all elements are properties then you don't need the `OfType` thing